# Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I've been trying to add ***user associations*** to the */campgrounds* but suddenly this error came up

```
Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
    at eval (C:\Users\karan\Desktop\YelpCamp\V9\views\campgrounds\show.ejs:20:44)
    at show (C:\Users\karan\Desktop\YelpCamp\V9\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:656:17)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\karan\Desktop\YelpCamp\V9\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:254:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\karan\Desktop\YelpCamp\V9\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:459:10)
    at View.render (C:\Users\karan\Desktop\YelpCamp\V9\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\karan\Desktop\YelpCamp\V9\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\karan\Desktop\YelpCamp\V9\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\karan\Desktop\YelpCamp\V9\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at C:\Users\karan\Desktop\YelpCamp\V9\routes\campgrounds.js:53:21
    at C:\Users\karan\Desktop\YelpCamp\V9\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4883:16
    at C:\Users\karan\Desktop\YelpCamp\V9\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:24:16
    at C:\Users\karan\Desktop\YelpCamp\V9\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4906:21
    at C:\Users\karan\Desktop\YelpCamp\V9\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4390:11
    at C:\Users\karan\Desktop\YelpCamp\V9\node_modules\kareem\index.js:135:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
```

These are the following files in which I put a code of user associations in *router.post* the method in campground.js file and through the show.ejs file I want to display the username

Please help me out

**app.js**

```
var express       = require("express"),
    app           = express(),
    bodyParser    = require("body-parser"),
    mongoose      = require("mongoose"),
    passport      = require('passport'),
    LocalStrategy = require('passport-local'),
    Campground    = require("./models/campground"),
    Comment       = require('./models/comment'),
    User          =require('./models/user.js'),
    seedDB        = require('./seeds');

    //Requiring Routes
var campgroundRoutes = require('./routes/campgrounds'),
    commentRoutes    = require('./routes/comments'),
    indexRoutes      = require('./routes/index');

// seedDB();   //Seed the database
    
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"))



//map global promise - to get rid of warning
mongoose.Promise =global.Promise;

//connect to mongoose
mongoose.connect("something",{
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})
.then(() => console.log("MongoDB connected..."))
.catch(err => console.log(err))
     
//Passport Configuration 
app.use(require("express-session")({
    secret : "Once Again",
    resave : false,
    saveUninitialized : false
}))
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
app.use(function(req,res, next){
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    next();
});

app.use('/', indexRoutes);
app.use('/campgrounds', campgroundRoutes);
app.use('/campgrounds/:id/comments', commentRoutes);



const port=3002;
app.listen(port, function(){
   console.log(`The YelpCamp Server is running on ${port}`);
});
```

**campground.js**

```
var express    = require('express');
var router     = express.Router();
var Campground = require('../models/campground')
    

    //INDEX - show all campgrounds
    router.get("/", function(req, res){
        // Get all campgrounds from DB
        Campground.find({}, function(err, allCampgrounds){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("campgrounds/index",{campgrounds: allCampgrounds });
        }
        });
    });

    //CREATE - add new campground to DB
    router.post("/", isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
        // get data from form and add to campgrounds array
        var name = req.body.name;
        var image = req.body.image;
        var desc = req.body.description;
        var author = {
            id: req.user._id,
            username: req.user.username
        };
        var newCampground = {name: name, image: image, description: desc, author:author};
        // Create a new campground and save to DB
        Campground.create(newCampground, function(err, newlyCreated){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                //redirect back to campgrounds page
                res.redirect("/campgrounds");
            }
        });
    });

    //NEW - show form to create new campground
    router.get("/new", isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
        res.render("campgrounds/new"); 
    });

    // SHOW - shows more info about one campground
    router.get("/:id", function(req, res){
        //find the campground with provided ID
        Campground.findById(req.params.id).populate("comments").exec(function(err, foundCampground){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                //render show template with that campground
                res.render("campgrounds/show", {campground: foundCampground});
            }
        });
    })
    
    //Middleware
    function isLoggedIn(req, res, next){
        if (req.isAuthenticated()){
            return next();
        }
        res.redirect('/login');
    } 

module.exports = router;
```

**show.ejs**

```
<%- include ('../partials/header') %> 

   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-3">
            <p class="lead">Yelp Camp</p>
            <div class="list-group">
               <div class="list-group-item active"> Option 1</div>
               <div class="list-group-item"> Option 2</div>
               <div class="list-group-item"> Option 3</div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="img-thumbnail mb-3">
               <img class="img-responsive mb-3"  style="width: 100%" src="<%= campground.image %>">
               <div class="caption-full">
                  <h4 class="float-right">$9.00/night</h4>
                  <h4><a href="#" ><%= campground.name %></a></h4>
                  <p><%= campground.description %></p>
                  <p>
                     <em>Submitted by: <%= campground.author.username %></em>
                 </p>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card bg-light" style="padding: 9px;">
               <div class="text-right mt-3 mr-3">
                  <a class="btn btn-success " href="/campgrounds/<%= campground._id %>/comments/new">Add Comment</a>
               </div>   
               <hr>           
               <% campground.comments.forEach(function(comment){ %>
                  <div class="row ">
                     <div class="col-md-12">
                        <strong> <%= comment.author.username %> </strong>
                        <span class="float-right">10 Days ago</span>
                        <p>
                           <%= comment.text %>
                        </p>
                     </div>
                  </div>  
               <% }) %>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>

   </div>

<%- include ('../partials/footer') %>
```

**UPDATED**

After rechecking my code, found that i just forgotten to declare the author variable in campground models

just a little bit of code

```
author :{
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        },
        username: String
    },
```

Comment: The code looks reasonable to me. What do you get if you were to `console.log` the campground?

Answer (score 1):

Got it, Let's create other file, name it for example passport.js Put all strategies and configurations into that file, and export passport.js from that file. And finally in app.js, import that file instead of importing actual passport.js

like this :

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((_id, done) => {
  User.findById( _id, (err, user) => {
    if(err){
        done(null, false, {error:err});
    } else {
        done(null, user);
    }
  });
});
```